# How to scroll CupertinoDatePicker with mouse drags?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino, cupertinopicker

I used a `CupertinoDatePicker` in a Flutter project that also should be deployed as a web app. But the `CupertinoDatePicker` only reacts to the mouse wheel, not to drag events. I think that this is unexpected behavior for many users.
Is there a way to tell the `CupertinoDatePicker` that it should also be draggable in addition to listening for mouse scroll events?

Code to reproduce:

```dart
CupertinoDatePicker(
  onDateTimeChanged: (v) => print(v),
),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the scroll behavior and enable mouse drag like

```dart
ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
  child: CupertinoDatePicker(
    onDateTimeChanged: (v) => print(v),
  ),
),
```

```dart
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        // etc.
      };
}
```

More about [default-scroll-behavior-drag migration-guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag#migration-guide)